# Scrapy CrawlSpider - Cannot Follow specific Links or Parse with custom handler

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been using Scrapy and attempting to follow examples to only follow url's that match some sort of regular expression.

I am not a Python developer but I have tried a lot of techniques to try and get this going.

I am using the sample URL in the Scrapy documentation and extending from `CrawlSpider` and implmentingg rules via `LinkExtractor`.

Currently I would like to just use a custom parser for any URL's that contain the word 'friend' in them.

** Scrapy Python Spider **

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'

    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='(friends)'), callback='parse_custom')
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        self.logger.info('1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! %s', response.url)

        for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_custom(self, response):
        # I have never been able to get this to call
        self.logger.info('2222222222222 - Parsing CUSTOM URL! %s', response.url)

        for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse)
```

**Log File**

```
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/miracles/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/miracle/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/live/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/life/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/inspirational/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/choices/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/abilities/page/1/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/simile/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/miracles/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/miracle/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/live/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/life/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/inspirational/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/choices/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/abilities/page/1/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/simile/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/truth/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/friends/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/friendship/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/reading/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/books/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/truth/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/friends/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/friendship/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/reading/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/books/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/
2017-07-30 10:45:59 [example] INFO: 1111111111111 - Parsing General URL! http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

*When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using `parse` as callback, since the `CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the `parse` method, the crawl spider will no longer work.*

Comment: Thanks, I even partially remember reading about that while going through the docs.